# Check if computer has BIOS password using C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, bios

I'm not sure if this is possible since I can't find any article regarding this. I'm looking for a way to check if a computer's BIOS has a password set or not (return true/false)

Tried the code here https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/305227/how-to-get-bios-information-in-csharp-desktop-appl but below are the only properties I was able to extract:

BiosCharacteristics,
BIOSVersion,
BuildNumber,
Caption,
CodeSet,
CurrentLanguage,
Description,
EmbeddedControllerMajorVersion,
EmbeddedControllerMinorVersion,
IdentificationCode,
InstallableLanguages,
InstallDate,
LanguageEdition,
ListOfLanguages,
Manufacturer,
Name,
OtherTargetOS,
PrimaryBIOS,
ReleaseDate,
SerialNumber,
SMBIOSBIOSVersion,
SMBIOSMajorVersion,
SMBIOSMinorVersion,
SMBIOSPresent,
SoftwareElementID,
SoftwareElementState,
Status,
SystemBiosMajorVersion,
SystemBiosMinorVersion,
TargetOperatingSystem,
Version

[image: BIOS Password]

Comment: There is n way to do this without knowing the specific model of BIOS and being able to directly communicate with it, this is not part of the standard driver. It is *possible*, it's just different for each model

Comment: Yeah vendor specific. Maybe there is some standard. Found this sample @dell https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/de-de/000146401/check-if-a-bios-password-is-set